# Is this a perhaps a GCC issue/bug

Tags: c, debugging, gcc

While I was solving today's AOC challenge I stumbled upon an interesting phenomenon where it appears that there is a problem with the GCC compiler or I have done something incorrect which I have yet to realize.

In the below code, I am parsing a list of numbers offset on a line read from a file input.txt:

```
  Starting items: 83, 62, 93
```

Something appears to go wrong when storing the result in the num variable. I have yet to check the disassembly to see what is going on.

```c
#include "stdio.h"
#include "stdlib.h"
#include "../../includes/fmt.c"

void problem();

int main() {

    FILE * fp = fopen("input.txt", "r");
    char * line = NULL;
    size_t len = 0;
    
    size_t length = (getline(&line, &len, fp) - 16) >> 2;
    problem(line, length);
}

void problem(char * line, size_t length) {
    for (size_t i = 0; i < length; ++i) {
        int num = 10 * (line[18 + (i << 2)]-'0')
                     + (line[19 + (1 << 2)]-'0');
        println("{2i: = }", num, 10 * (line[18 + (i << 2)]-'0')
                                    + (line[19 + (i << 2)]-'0'));
    }
}
```

Output:

```
82 = 83
62 = 62
92 = 93
```

I know that the error is not in my custom print function as I have tried without it.

So my question is. Is this a fault of my own or perhaps an error of the GCC?

Linux 5.15.82-1-lts x86_64
GCC 12.2.0

Comment: Your prototype of `problem` is incomplete; I recommend deleting that and just moving the definition of `problem` to be above `main`.  Also, `println` is not part of the C standard so we can't really debug this; please provide a [mcve].

Comment: You have a typo: you wrote `1 << 2` instead of `i << 2` in one location.

Comment: It's one of the fundamental rules of computing: If you think you've found a bug in the compiler, you haven't.  The problem is virtually always in your own code.

Comment: It is always your code. It is very unlikely beginner to write code which will not be correctly compiled/linked

Comment: @DavidGrayson: `void problem();` does not have an “incomplete prototype” because is not a prototype and does not contain a prototype. As defined by the C standard, a *function prototype* is a declaration of a function that declares the types of its parameters. A declaration of a function that does not declare the types of the parameters is just a declaration, not any sort of prototype. This is important because some of the rules in the standard depend on whether or not there is a function prototype.

Comment: If I recall correctly, in 12.7 years on Stack Overflow, with 4,848 answers and who knows how many questions seen, I have seen two C compiler bugs reported by new participants. So you can bound the odds on “Is this a perhaps a GCC issue/bug?”

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like there may be an error in the code on the line

```
int num = 10 * (line[18 + (i << 2)]-'0') + (line[19 + (1 << 2)]-'0');
```

The index of the second character being read appears to be incorrect. Instead of `line[19 + (1 << 2)]`, it should be `line[19 + (i << 2)]` to access the correct character in the string.